# Unable to perform Sqoop import

Tags: import, sqoop

I am unable to import data from Mysql to Hdfs.My bashrc & sqoop-env.sh files are fine. Also I am able to run sqoop list-databases command successfully. The problem is with import command it is throwin an outputconnectionfailed exception please refer to below error & help me out:

> Blockquote
>   rahul@ubuntu:~$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/rahul
>   --username root --password 123 --table emp -m1 --target-dir /sqoopimport/emp Warning: /usr/lib/hbase does not exist! HBase imports
>   will fail. Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase
>   installation. 14/09/09 01:22:45 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your
>   password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
>   14/09/09 01:22:45 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL
>   streaming resultset. 14/09/09 01:22:45 INFO tool.CodeGenTool:
>   Beginning code generation 14/09/09 01:22:45 INFO manager.SqlManager:
>   Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `emp` AS t LIMIT 1 14/09/09
>   01:22:45 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.*
>   FROM `emp` AS t LIMIT 1 14/09/09 01:22:45 INFO orm.CompilationManager:
>   HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop Note:
>   /tmp/sqoop-rahul/compile/a81597835880664d34a2ff0e4c7b9b33/emp.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. 14/09/09 01:22:46 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file:
>   /tmp/sqoop-rahul/compile/a81597835880664d34a2ff0e4c7b9b33/emp.jar
>   14/09/09 01:22:46 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are
>   importing from mysql. 14/09/09 01:22:46 WARN manager.MySQLManager:
>   This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct 14/09/09 01:22:46 WARN
>   manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.
>   14/09/09 01:22:46 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME
>   behavior to convertToNull (mysql) 14/09/09 01:22:46 INFO
>   mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of emp 14/09/09 01:22:47
>   INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201409090100_0003 14/09/09
>   01:22:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 14/09/09 01:22:54
>   INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409090100_0003_m_000000_0,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:193)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:355)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:278)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:187)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:305)
>           ... 26 more
>
> 14/09/09 01:22:54 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task
>   outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:22:54 WARN mapred.JobClient:
>   Error reading task outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:22:59 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409090100_0003_m_000000_1,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:193)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:355)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:278)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:187)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:305)
>           ... 26 more
>
> 14/09/09 01:22:59 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task
>   outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:22:59 WARN mapred.JobClient:
>   Error reading task outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:23:03 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409090100_0003_m_000000_2,
>   Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications l
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:193)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
>           ... 9 more Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds
>   ago. The driver has not received any packets
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:355)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:278)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:187)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>           at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>           at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>           at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:425)
>           at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:241)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:305)
>           ... 26 more
>
> 14/09/09 01:23:03 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task
>   outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:23:03 WARN mapred.JobClient:
>   Error reading task outputConnection refused 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201409090100_0003 14/09/09
>   01:23:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 6 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=20325 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after
>   reserving slots (ms)= 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
>   14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
>   14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
>   14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
>   14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in
>   23.174 seconds (0 bytes/sec) 14/09/09 01:23:09 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records. 14/09/09 01:23:09 ERROR
>   tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that I was using localhost in the import statement, as the sql was running in the same system. when I used the actual IP instead of localhost. then it worked like a charm.

Also i was using root username & password to connect to sql. for some reason it didn't work.So I created another user & granted all privileges to that user.

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON employee.* to 'sqoopuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'passphrase';

Mistake:sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/rahul --username root --password 123 --table emp -m1 --target-dir /sqoopimport/emp

Correction:sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.202.139:3306/rahul --username sqoopuser --password 123 --table emp -m1 --target-dir /sqoopimport/emp

Answer (score 0):

There are three checkpoints:

1. Make sure mysql service accessible ->  Manually connect to `localhost:3306` as `root`.
2. Make sure no firewall restriction to `localhost:3306`
3. Download the most recent mysql-connector to lib and then import again.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution in my case was to use the proper IP address instead of the "localhost" in sqoop command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.69.69:3306/testdb --username root -P --table TESTABLE --target-dir /data/import
```